# CSS Text Align Center Not Working When Additional Div Is Added

Tags: css

I have a mobile website header. The "Page Title" should be centered and the "Back" button should float to the left. The "Page Title" is perfectly centered until I add the "Back" button. Once the "Back" button is added the "Page Title" is "somewhat" centered but is pushed to the right. What am I missing.

My code and Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9C2SS/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: #666;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.pageTitle {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: large;   
    background: #2281b5;
}
.backArrow {
    float: left;    
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pageTitle">
<div class="backArrow">
Back
</div>
Page Title</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's over to the right slightly because it is being moved by the back button. You can remove the back button from document flow by absolute positioning.
Like this:

```
.backArrow {
    position:absolute;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9C2SS/3/) ?

Position your button absolutely, so it will be removed from the normal flow of the document and your title will automatically center.

```
.backArrow {    
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
}
```